# Ignore Case with XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

Is there a way to get XML Unit to ignore case when comparing two XMl documents? Both the tags and their values...  is the same to me as ?

XMLUnit give me the following Difference: `Expected attribute value 'FALSE' but was 'false'`

I tried simply using `.toUpperCase()` on both of the input strings but then I get this error:

`[Fatal Error] :1:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not     allowed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.java:383)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.java:370)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:101)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:93)`

Any ideas of a different way to do this? Or a way to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

So if I use `.toLowerCase()` it works... Something to do with the Doctype being in uppercase causes a problem or something like that...

Comment: although still, a way to tell XMLUnit to ignore the case would be cool :)